I need to create a static Linked List in Marie assembler
I am working on the following task:

Create the following static Linked List in Marie assembler, and add Marie code, using loop to traverse the list and display each node value such as 9, 4, 14. end loop after 14.
/node, data link
    
next = head         // Head  always points to the 1st node. 
while next != None
     print node value
     advance next pointer to point to next node
wend


I just can't figure out how to write code that will display 9, 4, 14 in a loop.
My code so far:
ORG 100  
HEAD, DEC 102 / Head pointer points to the first node
NODE1, DEC 9 / Value of Node 1
NODE2, DEC 4 / Value of Node 2
NODE3, DEC 14 / Value of Node 3
NEXT1, DEC 9 / Link from Node 1 to Node 2
NEXT2, DEC 4 / Link from Node 2 to Node 3
NEXT3, DEC 14 / Link from Node 3 to None (end of the list)
NEXT4, DEC 0

// Traversal loop to display node values
LOOP, Load  HEAD / Load the head pointer into AC
  Output  / Output the value of the current node
  Load  HEAD / Load the next pointer into AC
  Store  HEAD / Update the HEAD pointer
  SKIPCOND 400 / Skip if the pointer is not None
  JUMP LOOP / Continue looping if the pointer is not None
  Halt  / Halt the program when reaching the end of the list

// End of the program
HALT

How can I make this work?

Please define the linked list node in pseudo code, I think your problem is translating that (not shown) to MARIE data.  Also, expand on the statements within the loop of pseudo code, using this linked list node definition.  In order to write assembly code, you need to get specific: "advance next pointer to point to next node" is vague, and the way to fix that is to have a well-defined concept of the linked list node structure.

This is how the the professor placed it. this why it's hard to figure out. i have asked him for help but he hasn't replied back.

The following refines the pseudo code:
struct node { struct node *nextNode, int data; }

struct node node1 { &node2, 9 };
struct node node2 { &node3, 4 };
struct node node3 { null, 14 }

struct node *head = &node1;

struct node *next = head;
while ( next != null ) {
    print next->data;
    next = next->nextNode;
}

Try to put that into assembly.
Your current assembly code has 2 arrays, one for values and one (broken one) for nexts.
You need instead one array of item pairs — just one array, where the elements are pairs of items, rather than two separate arrays.

You have not really created the linked list. For instance, with this:
NEXT1, DEC 9 / Link from Node 1 to Node 2

... you don't link to Node 2, but merely have stored a value that happens to be the same value as Node 2 has. You would really need to store a memory reference there.
I would suggest to store your linked list as (value, next) pairs -- one pair for each node. A pair would be encoded as two data items that are consecutive, i.e. whose memory addresses only differ by 1.
To make it less trivial, and to make sure an implementation really follows the links of the linked list, I would encode the static list in a different order than the logical order for those three nodes. Using the ADR type specifier, you could encode your linked list as follows:
Head,   ADR Node1 / Pointer to the first node
Node2,  DEC 4     / Value of the second node
        ADR Node3 / Pointer to the node that comes after the second node
Node1,  DEC 9     / Value of the first node
        ADR Node2 / Pointer to the node that comes after the first node
Node3,  DEC 14    / Value of the third node
        DEC -1    / To denote end of the list (NIL pointer)

Then you need to be able to read a pointer (address) from memory, and then get that value at that address into the accumulator. You have tried this will a simple Load instruction, like this:
Load  HEAD / Load the head pointer into AC

But that just loads the contents stored at HEAD in the AC. The comment does not reflect what happens here. What you really want to do is called indirect addressing, and MARIE has instructions for that (including LoadI).
The loop you have provided in pseudo code can then be written like this:
        Load Head
        Store Next
Repeat, Skipcond 800
        Halt
        LoadI Next  / Read first member of the node (its value)
        Output
        / Move pointer to second member of the node (its next pointer)
        Load Next 
        Add One
        Store Next
        / Follow the node's next pointer
        LoadI Next 
        Store Next
        Jump Repeat

/ Hard-coded linked list (constants):
Head,   ADR Node1 / Pointer to the first node
Node2,  DEC 4     / Value of the second node
        ADR Node3 / Pointer to the node that comes after the second node
Node1,  DEC 9     / Value of the first node
        ADR Node2 / Pointer to the node that comes after the first node
Node3,  DEC 14    / Value of the third node
        DEC -1    / To denote end of the list (NIL pointer)

/ Address of the current node
Next,   ADR 0
/ Constant
One,    DEC 1

You can assemble and run this code on MARIE.js.org.
